# From an equation to a total differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider an equation of the form
$u(x,y)=c$ where $c$ is a constant. This equation says nothing if it's not calculated, giving the set of points $(x,y)$ for which $u(x,y)=c$.

Starting from $u(x,y)=c$, which are the logical and conceptual passages that allows me to derive the equation $du=0$ ?

I ask this because from books these things are often taken for granted, but i often don't understand the deep reasons...

Comment: $du=0$ only holds if you *restrict* to a level curve $u(x,y)=c$. You have to give more context to your question, but—as it stands—that's all I can say. Do you know differential forms?

Comment: What does $du=0$ represent implicitely ? Is it a set of points ?

Answer (score 0):

In classical terminology, the total differential $du$ is defined by
$$du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy.$$
There are two interpretations of the equation $du=0$:

(1) We want the points $(x,y)$ where $du$ becomes exactly $0$, so this means that the gradient of $u$ vanishes at such points, or
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0.$$

(2) In the context of differential equations, we want curves along which
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy=0, \quad\text{i.e.,}\quad \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}.$$
These curves will be level curves of the function $u(x,y)$.

For example, if $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, in the first interpretation we find precisely the origin, and in the second interpretation we find the circles $x^2+y^2=c$ for $c\ge 0$. (When $c=0$, it's not really a circle, and this is the point we had in the first interpretation.)